# Partitioning or not partitioning the data with random forests when sample is limited

Tags: r, random-forest

I am struggling to decide if I should or should not partition a dataset for ranking variable importance by means of random forests.

From a sample of 130 individuals (already averaged from 800 data points, including repetitions) there are 2 generations of individuals. But there are few data points overlapping both age curves. So, there are few young individuals from the second generation and few old individuals from the first generation. I sampled ALL of those and cannot increase more the sample size.

I am trying to separate the effcets between the variables age and generation, according to my previous power analysis the sample should be just enough (including ALL 130).

I am ranking 6 variables by conditional random forests, including age and generation. The results differ when I use 100% of my dataset for the rankings vs 70% for training, 15% for validation and 15% for testing. This is most probable linked to the small sample size of mid-aged ("overlapped") individuals when I test for 70% of the sample.

Intuitively, I would think the most appropiate is to rank the variables using 100% of the data. At the end this is the reason I spent a year gathering the few mid-aged individuals and I would think this gives more robustness to the analyses. However, I am hesitating if this would be correct to do.